# What's the fastest way to do a day trip from San Diego to Tijuana?

Tags: day-trips, san-diego, tijuana

I'm going to be staying in San Diego for 2 weeks and would like to travel to Tijuana 2-3 times for a day trip. I'm a Global Entry member but I'll have a rental car, so I won't be able to use SENTRI lanes to come back.

What's the fastest way to make this day trip? To avoid "fly by helicopter" as an answer, my maximum transportation budget is $100 for the day.

Comment: @Midavalo get food, go to their side of the border wall, check out the city, maybe get a haircut. I won't need my car.

Comment: There's so much more to TJ than just that.  The tequila bars, the burros painted as Zebras, the gun battles!  There's something for everyone.

Comment: @PeterM the... gun battles? As in, shoot outs between gangs?

Comment: TJ is currently averaging over 5 murders per day.  Which puts it up there in world standings.  So there is scope to see almost anything.  I wouldn't say don't go and I'm not trying to scare you, but for any area that has potential for violence and crime I would do my own research (which saved me from being robbed in Buenos Aires one time).  Using common sense would be the starting point, but it's always what you don't know that will get you.  So reading things like [this blog](https://wheretheroadforks.com/is-tijuana-safe-avoiding-common-scams-and-crime/) is useful.

Comment: @PeterM unless you go looking for it you're unlikely to see "gun battles" in TJ.  Most violent crime in TJ is either cartel vs cartel (or people who owe them money), or domestic.  You're more likely to be done by thieves or scams (same as many tourist hotspots around the world), so stay street savvy and you'll be OK.

Comment: @Midavalo Totally agree.  But there's always the chance of getting lucky!

Comment: A lot of rental car companies don't want you taking their cars across the border anyway, at least without buying extra insurance. Be sure to check the rental agency's policies if you are thinking abut driving. Last time I rented a car in San Diego they specifically asked me if it was something I was planning to do at the counter.

Comment: @JonathanReez What month are you planning on traveling to San Diego, and what part of the city is your hotel?

Comment: @Midavalo I’ll be there in 2 weeks. Staying at Ocean Beach neighborhood

Answer (score 9):

As someone who lives in the area, any time I hear of someone planning on coming down I tell them to walk across the border unless they specifically need a car.

If you're planning on being further out than just TJ then a car is recommended, but if you plan on staying within the city, and only for a day or two, then my recommendation is to walk across the border - bring your passport (or passport card) and your Global Entry card.  The Tourist Zone is a very short Uber from the border.

Uber will get you anywhere you need to go for very little money.  I can uber from the border to Rosarito (the next city to the south) for $10 USD, so anywhere within TJ should be in that range or less.

There will be taxis (you will need to speak Spanish) or Uber as soon as you're down the ramp from the border crossing.  Make sure your phone plan has international or Mexico roaming enabled otherwise you won't be able to get your Uber!

A passport or passport card is officially required for entry into Mexico.  You may or may not be asked for one, but always best to have one just-in-case.

Comment: Do I also need to get an FMM for a day trip within Tijuana city borders?

Comment: Nvm, [found your answer on this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/159564/does-a-french-with-us-green-card-need-a-mexico-s-visitor-visa-fmm-when-enterin)

Comment: @JonathanReez in practice, the answer is no.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Just don't get asked for one by police

Comment: @Midavalo I got stopped by the police right after crossing into Mexico one day because I mistook their car with my Uber, they searched me for drugs and looked at my passport, but didn't care about FMM. MX border officers also never asked me for FMM.  So I think really unlikely.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I personally know people who have been sent back to the US because they didn't have an FMM on them.  I have been asked to show Residency or FMM on more than one occasion.  It is happening more often.  Just because you were lucky that one time doesn't mean it doesn't happen.  Legally it's required, and it's free for less than 7 days.

Answer (score 5):

If you need a car in Tijuana and Didi/Uber don't suffice: drive back and forth. Crossing from the US to Mexico typically just take a few minutes. On the way back, try to pick a time with a minimum waiting time. To see the wait time: https://bwt.cbp.gov/index.html 30 to 45 minutes in the evening is quite common in the ready lane. [Where can one see the border waiting time in real time or historical data, for people queuing from the US to Mexico?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/171849/1810) be careful if you have windows tint: https://law.stackexchange.com/q/76605/31 also you might need to purchase a car insurance for Mexico.

If you don't need a car in Tijuana: park near the border entry on the US side and walk through the border. There are plenty of paid parking lots near the border. Walking back to the US in the evening with global entry typically only takes a few minutes. You can get a cab/Didi/Uber right after crossing MX or US on foot. Didi is currently typically the cheaper option. [San Ysidro Border Parking Options?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/76198/1810) ; [For how long can one leave one's car parked in San Diego Old Town's free parking lots?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/159680/1810)

FYI: [Does a French with US green card need a Mexico’s Visitor Visa (FMM) when entering Mexico by land for a few days, and if so can it be done at border?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/159564/1810)

Comment: The CBP border wait times are notoriously inaccurate

Comment: @Midavalo was reasonably accurate the few times I used it in San Diego in the evening from MX to US.

Comment: +1 for the park near the border and walk across

Comment: Can you clarify where exactly I should park the car? I'm a bit confused looking at Google Maps. Can I get a cab/Uber right after crossing on foot?

Comment: @JonathanReez You can take the Trolley from SD downtown right to the border, then walk across.  If you want to park near the border there is a large shopping plaza where you can park for a few hours, otherwise there are longer-term parking around for a fee.

Comment: @JonathanReez plenty of paid parking lot near the border, you can walk from there to the MX entry. You can get a cab/Didi/Uber right after crossing on foot.

Comment: @JonathanReez please be aware that the "Old Town" parking mentioned in one of the questions Franck has linked to is **north** of San Diego downtown.  There is a LOT of parking available there, and could be a good option for you (and while there, take a look around the historic area), but it may seem odd if you're driving north to park.  That said, there is also a lot of parking available at or near the border, and IIRC you'll need to switch trolley to get from Old Town to the border (although that's not hard)

Answer (score 3):

The [San Diego light rail system](https://www.sdmts.com/schedules-real-time-maps-and-routes/trolley) has a station across the street from the CBP entry point.   It's a straight shot from north and downtown.

The run is fast, it is on dedicated railroad right-of-way once it gets out of downtown. It's about a 45 minute run from the Santa Fe depot (the hub) to the border (San Ysidro).

Check their website but most stations, especially suburban ones, have parking.

[image]
[src](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:San_Diego_Trolley_September_2012.svg). *Orange line now goes to Arnele Ave.*

Arrive a few minutes early to the station, and find a ticket vending machine at the station.  It will sell you a ticket valid from "now" until a few hours from now.  Don't board without it; you cannot buy a ticket on the train.

The system uses a modified honor system, called "Proof of Payment", where a fare inspector *might* check everyone for a valid ticket. Not having one is a civil infraction like a speeding ticket.  This can also be done on a smart phone via an "app" but I advise doing it before boarding, because they have safeguards to prevent people from buying tickets only when they see a fare inspector coming...

Despite being called a "trolley", it's actually an interurban using an old railroad line - the San Diego & Arizona Eastern, in fact - known for the world's largest trestle at Carrizo Gorge.

Obviously you have to evaluate public transit vs the still-lingering COVID-19 risks. Masks are [still required](https://www.sdmts.com/schedules-real-time/covid-19-updates) on public transit because immunocompromised people have to ride it too.

Comment: What's the optimal place to park my car though, assuming my hotel is far from a station?

Comment: @JonathanReez If you're a long drive from a station I gather you're not downtown.  Suburban stations will have parking, check their website.